# JBoss EAP 7-7.3 environment variables: standalone vs. domain

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

How to use env variables for datasource properties in JBOSS EAP 7.3? It does not work on my local machine and in docker also.

Here is datasource part of my standalone-full.xml file

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/powds" pool-name="powpu" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${env.CONNECTION_URL}:ddjboss</connection-url>
                        <driver>oracle</driver>
                        <pool>
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>true</prefill>
                            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                            <allow-multiple-users>false</allow-multiple-users>
                        </pool>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>${env.ORACLE_USERNAME}</user-name>
                            <password>${env.ORACLE_PASSWORD}</password>
                        </security>
                    </datasource>
```

For example I try to start container like here and env values not replacing. `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 -p 7001:7001 patient/patient:2.0 -e ORACLE_PASSWORD="cl_cn_local_upd" -e ORACLE_USERNAME="user"`

How I set env variable in docker:

```
ENV CONNECTION_URL=lovalhost:9909
```

Comment: You won't be able to refer to arbitrary environment variables of your OS/container from jboss eap's configuration. You could start the server with specific java_opts you'd be able to refer to, but I think the cleanest would be to run a CLI command to create your specific datasource. Is this something that could work for you?

Comment: Hello, thank you. I want to start docker container and add datasource parameters as env variables and replace in standalone.xml. For example I try to start container like here and env values not replacing. docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 -p 7001:7001 patient/patient:2.0  -e ORACLE_PASSWORD="cl_cn_local_upd" -e ORACLE_USERNAME="user"

Comment: I feel like environment variable are inappropriate for your purpose (which I understand is being able to easily configure different database connections for your different containers based on the same docker image). My point of view is based on two points : 1) you can't directly refer to your container's environment variables from JBoss EAP's configuration ; 2) these include sensitive information (the DB user's credentials) and the fewer places they will appear in the better

Comment: If security is a concern, you should check out [credentials stores](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/how_to_configure_server_security/securely_storing_credentials) where I believe you would be able to include all those parameters and refer to them from your XML configuration.

Comment: If you want to do that anyway I think you'll have to use a startup script that will transform your environment properties into JAVA_OPTS before calling the standard startup script

Comment: You might want to take a look at this RedHat documentation which describes how the editor recommends configuration modifications should be applied : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/using_the_red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform_docker_image/extending-the-image#modifying_the_configuration

Comment: I added prams to JAVA_OPTS but standalone.xml file still not see values.

Comment: you should at least remove the `env.` prefix from your references if you haven't done so yet, but I'm now not as sure as before that it is possible to directly refer to java opts from your configuration. I might have been thinking about the system-properties you can define in your configuration. Testing now, I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: Modifying the JAVA_OPTS should work fine in order to create what is considered as system-properties from inside the configuration, but it's easier to just pass them to the standalone.sh, no need for any script change actually. More info [there](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/configuration_guide/jboss_eap_management#system_properties). This doesn't mention using them to configure your datasource though, but I think it should work if you use the syntax `${systemPropertyName}` where you need them.

Comment: Also, I've found some references to the `${env.envvarName}` syntax you were trying to use, but only in old threads that most likely concerned the community version. Not sure they ever were implemented in EAP.

Comment: set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -DORACLE_PASSWORD=12312312"and  <password>${ORACLE_PASSWORD}</password>  also not working,

Comment: That syntax (`set` and `%envar%`) is for windows, is it the OS your containers are running? I though docker was unix-only

Comment: You can verify the correct application of the JAVA_OPTS by looking at the output of `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jinfo <pid>` (or `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jinfo <pid>` for windows) where <pid> should be replaced by the pid of the JVM running your standalone

Comment: Sorry but it's not working anyway/ Standalone xml file ignore env and system variables.

Comment: I feel like system-properties should work, but if you're sure you've made no mistake the only solution then is to use your variables in a CLI command used to create the datasource. The RedHat doc I linked above mentions how to modify configuration in the context of docker. It doesn't describe how to use variables, but uses variables the jboss image defines ($JBOSS_HOME) so I guess you should be able to do the same

Comment: To be clear, what I'm suggesting is to remove the datasource from your standalone.xml and have your container create it by calling `jboss-cli.sh` at startup. The CLI command to run would be something like `/subsystem=datasources/datasource=powpu:add(...)`

Comment: jboss-cli.sh is good solution, thanks